# Unity: проблемы с 2d коллайдером

Tags: unity3d

У меня есть коллайдер и  две коробки. Когда коробка сталкивается с коллайдером - коллайдер меняет `transform.position`, коробки на дефолтные, координаты(в начало). В самом начале коробки прижаты друг к другу, но с каждым переносом позиции коробок на начало - коробки отжимаются друг от друга, а нужно чтобы они оставались прижатыми друг к другу.

Не могу понять в чем проблема, ведь для коробок используется один и тот же скрипт?

Короткое видео - https://vk.com/video174341022_456239035

P.S заметил что столкновение коллайдеров коробки и коллайдера-ограничителя всегда разное, т.е столкновение может произойти на координате -25 по X, а в следующий раз уже на -24

Также думал может дело в скорости перемещения коробок, я отключил ограничитель и пустил коробки в сцене. Они летели очень долго и не отрывались друг от друга, т.е скорость совершенно одинаковая.

Коробка(Hazard):

```
public class Hazard : MonoBehaviour {

    private Transform transform;

    public float speed;
    public float range;
    private int count;
    private Vector3 position;
    private Vector3 defaultPosition;


    void Start () {
        transform = GetComponent<Transform>();
        defaultPosition = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
        position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
        count = 0;
    }

    void FixedUpdate () {
        position.x -= speed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position = position;
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D coll)
    {
        if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Rolling")
        {
            position = defaultPosition;
            transform.position = position;
            Debug.Log("position = defaultPosition;");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Вот твоя проблема, тут 3 итерации смещения. Проблема в том, что ты из-за триггера производишь 2 смещения(1 в fixedUpdate, 2 в TriggerEnter) за итерацию, а это ведет к не равномерному смещению.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что мне нужно сделать тогда?

Comment: @ВиталийБелоусов Синхронизировать очевидно,то есть нужен модуль который будет следить, чтобы между объектами не было разрыва и вносить изменения в ином случае.